# JQuery Datepicker in English with this format dd/mm/yy

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I can't set the date format to dd/mm/yy with a jQuery Datepicker, when the language locale of the browser is English, it takes always this other format: mm/dd/yy.

This is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

var from = $("#from");
var to = $("#to");
var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
var lang = document.getElementById("language").innerHTML;
$(function(){
      from.datepicker($.extend({
           dateFormat: dateFormat
           },
           $.datepicker.regional[lang]
     ));
     to.datepicker($.extend({
          dateFormat: dateFormat
          },
     $.datepicker.regional[lang]
));
```

With other languages it works. 
How could I set the European (dd/mm/yy) date format in English?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using [format](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) option in datepicker constructor for Bootstrap Datepicker or [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option for jQuery UI Datepicker.

**Bootstrap example**

```js
$('input').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02/10/2017">
```

**jQuery UI example**

```js
$( "input" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02/10/2017">
```

Also you could define custom language settings and apply it by using `language` option.

**Bootstrap example**

```js
$.fn.datepicker.dates['my-language'] = {
    days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    today: "Today",
    clear: "Clear",
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    titleFormat: "MM yyyy"
};

$('input').datepicker({
  language: 'my-language'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02/10/2017">
```

**jQuery UI example**

```js
$.datepicker.regional[ "mylanguage" ] = {
 closeText: "Done",
 prevText: "Prev",
 nextText: "Next",
 currentText: "Today",
 monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June",
 "July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
 monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
 dayNames: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ],
 dayNamesShort: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ],
 dayNamesMin: [ "Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa" ],
 weekHeader: "Wk",
 dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
 firstDay: 1,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: "" };
$('input').datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "mylanguage" ]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02/10/2017">
```

Comment: I'm using the the standard jQuery Datepicker, not  the bootstrap-datepicker, which maybe could be a good alternative. I've added the scripts that I'm using to my code.
Thank's @Alexander

Comment: @AleixAlcover,  there are similar options  for jQuery UI Datepicker. I have updated my answer.